# How do you disable an email forwarder in Outlook when it is "Unable to load these settings"?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, outlook-web-access

We have a shared Office365 mailbox that I recently set to forward to a (free) external help-desk system, by going to,

`Settings Cog > View all outlook settings > Forwarding`

We are now moving to an IMAP solution, so need to turn this forwarder off. Unfortunately, I now see this when I go to the same place.

[image: Outlook.com Forwarding Options - Unable to load these settings. Please try again later]

Yep, it's the old "Unable to load these settings. Please try again later" of death. Because BSoD is so last decade.

We have;

- come back 24 seconds later
- come back 24 hours later
- tried going into [classic mode](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/cannot-set-up-automatic-forwarding-on-outlookcom/036e4d1b-94a5-4dc4-b850-6f0c1595d7ca)
  every time I do go into classic mode, the "Open another mailbox"
  button opens the shared mailbox in non-classic mode and then adding
  the classic mode URL does nothing.
- Looked for anything on the admin side that would let us change this

All have been unsuccessful. How do I go about disabling this forwarder?

Thanks in advance

James

Comment: Another day and "try again later" is clearly not working. I would be really grateful of any pointing in the right direction.

Comment: I was just able to remove the forwarder. We did not do anything. Thanks Microsoft logic.

Comment: Same thing is happening to me, what's the solution?

Comment: @Mike I have no idea. It just started working one day. I hate fixing things with magics but that is what happened on this occasion.

Answer (score 0):

As with all things Microsoft, try turning it off and on again - except this time wait a week in between!

Rubbish answer, sorry, but that's all we did.